# Full screen mode on dual desktop

Tags: c++, mfc, directx, direct3d, nvidia

I have an MFC application/dialog that goes into full-screen mode. I run it on a Windows 7 dual display with nVidia GT 330. I need to make it go-full screen on the second desktop (not primary display) from within the program, without any user input. Is this possible with Direct3D?

Answer (score 0):

You can move the window to the second desktop with Windows API, and switch to fullscreen if you are using D3D9 or earlier (The multi-monitor sample for D3D10 is still using this method though). If you have DXGI, you can set which monitor to use with the second parameter of SetFullscreenState.

Comment: I am using GDI+ to display the graphic. This is using Visual Studio 2005. Does GDI+ use D3D? If so, how do I find which version?

Comment: GDI+ is a pure software engine and has nothing to do with Direct3D. If you are not using Direct3D, fullscreen means just a borderless window occupying a whole desktop.